# Javascript push() function not adding to array

Tags: jquery

I've had a look at other similar questions, but so far none seem precisely applicable.

I'm trying to generate a string from data obtained from database and pushing it into an array for the Pickachoose jquery gallery which requires JSON as follows:

```
var a = [
  {"image":"../../1.jpg","caption":"Any donation is appreciated. PikaChoose is free to use!","link":"http://pikachoose.com","title":"Image 1"},
  {"image":"../../2.jpg","caption":"Be sure to check out <a href=\"http://www.pikachoose.com\">PikaChoose.com</a> for updates.","link":"http://pikachoose.com","title":"Image 2"},
  {"image":"../../3.jpg","caption":"You can use any type of html you want with PikaChoose","link":"http://pikachoose.com","title":"Image 3"}
 ];
$(".pikachoose").PikaChoose({data:a});
```

The above works if I hardcode it like that.

However, I am getting my data from a mySQL database using the following code:

```
    var a = [];

    $.getJSON("search.cfc?method=x&returnformat=json&queryformat=column",{"id":id},function(res,code){
         for (var i = 0; i<res.ROWCOUNT; i++) {
              var img = res.DATA.IMAGE[i].toLowerCase();
              var cap = res.DATA.CAPTION[i].toLowerCase();
              var lnk = res.DATA.LINK[i].toLowerCase();
              var ttl = res.DATA.TITLE[i].toLowerCase(); 
              var str = '{"image":"' + img + '","caption":"' + cap + '","link":"' + lnk + '","title":"' + ttl + '"}';  
              // str gives, e.g., {"image":["/images/website/retailers/logos/78/serena.jpg"],"caption":["ghsf"],"link":["jhghdfghd"],"title":["rtetuye"]}
              a.push(str); // problem here; doesn't push the string
         }

 });
```

So basically the array isn't being pushed to.

Comment: If you're getting the data from a MySQL database and you control the code for that, and you're returning the data as JSON, what's the point in splitting it up and re-forming JSON again? Just output the correct format from `search.cfc` and skip your client-side processing

Comment: You are supposed to push object not string.

Comment: When are you checking `a` to see if anything was pushed? If it's after the `getJSON()` call, `a` would still be empty, since the call is asynchronous. Checking it *inside* the `getJSON` success function, but after the loop, I'd expect `a` to have the strings appended.

Comment: @amit_g That would cause the *wrong* thing to be pushed, perhaps, but not *nothing* being pushed.

Comment: @PaulRoub, that is at least one of the problem (there could be more). The comment "// str gives, e.g." seems to indicate that the data is being returned. It is just not being transformed to a proper format. "nothing being pushed" is probably a deduction based on nothing being shown in the gallery vs. nothing really being in the array a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to push object not string. Change the `var str = ...` to

```
var str = {
    "image": img,
    "caption": cap,
    "link": lnk,
    "title": ttl
};
```